# for a given $f$, $f$ is measurable iff $f^{-1} (${$-\infty$}$) \in \mathcal{M}$ , $f^{-1} (${$\infty$}$) \in \mathcal{M}$ and f is measurable on $Y$.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $f : X \rightarrow \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ and $Y = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ then f is measurable iff $f^{-1} (${$-\infty$}$) \in \mathcal{M}$ , $f^{-1} (${$\infty$}$) \in \mathcal{M}$ and f is measurable on $Y$.

My approach :

$\Rightarrow$  $f$ is measurable thus we have $f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{M} $  $\forall E \in \mathcal{B}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}} $ 
now we know that $\mathcal{B}_{\bar{\mathbb{R}}} =\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}} \cup ${$-\infty$} $ \cup ${$\infty$} Thus now $f^{-1} (${$-\infty$}$) \in \mathcal{M}$ , $f^{-1} (${$\infty$}$) \in \mathcal{M}$ and also $f^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{M} $  $\forall E \in \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}} $ this is nothing but f is measurable on $Y$ ( As $f : Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Hence proved

$\Leftarrow$ NO clue !

Is my approach and first part of proof correct ? Someone please help.